# Javascript to insert decimal to the ones place onkeyup has period persist after clearing the textbox

Tags: javascript

I have some simple javascript that automatically inserts a decimal in the numbers as you type. Three functions for one, two, and three decimal places. The two and three decimal place functions work how I desire, where when you backspace or clear the textbox, the placeholder text is replaced. However the one decimal place function leaves the period in the textbox after backspacing or deleting. What do I need to do to allow it to function like the other two?

The functions are as follows:

```
function formatAsDollars1(el) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d?)$/, '.$1');
}

function formatAsDollars2(el) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d\d?)$/, '.$1');
}

function formatAsDollars3(el) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d\d\d?)$/, '.$1');
}
```

I set up a JSFiddle to show what I mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/doq8j3bz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why the last two functions work but the first one doesn't:

When inserting a `?` modifier, it only affects the last "element" in your regex. For example, `/\s\d?/` looks for a whitespace character followed by an optional digit, not an optional whitespace and digit.

So in the last two functions, it looks for one or two digits with an optional second or third digit to replace. However, in the 1 decimal function it looks for an optional digit, which is everything pretty much.

Therefore, removing the question mark should fix your error, i.e.

```
function formatAsDollars1(el) {
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d)$/, '.$1');
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the quick reply! Would you happen to know a clever way to combine the three functions into one to reduce the duplication of code? Or is the way that I have it sufficient?

Comment: @Guitrum one way is to write a function like this `function format(el, regex) { el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(regex, '.$1') }` and pass appropriate regexes in.

Comment: and then call the function by adding the attribute `onkeyup="format(this, /(\d)$/);"`?

Comment: @Guitrum just don't put the function call in quotes, then that code will be treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the question mark in your formatAsDollars1's replace regex:

```
function formatAsDollars1(el) {
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d)$/, '.$1');
}
```